# How to duplicate the tab using selenium and python?

Tags: python, selenium

I use chrome as my web-driver and I want to duplicate the tab as the following picture shows (action: click the right button on the tab and choose "duplicate"). In this way, the words I typed in the previous page will retain in the duplicated page. And it seems that I can't do it with opening the tab with the same URL (the words will disappear). Can someone tell me how to do it with selenium? Thanks very much!

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1bTbrtnT78xP3bHfQvt8xiVEIETwKWHvz/view?usp=sharing

Comment: Open a new tab with the same url

Comment: If I understand correctly your problem is that you do not want the page in the new tab to retain any form information from the previous page ? You should tell the readers in the text of your question. I think the forms of stackoverflows are filled using cookies.

Comment: I want the new tab retain the information from the previous page. If I use "duplicate" (click the right button on the tab and choose "duplicate"), it will retain the message. However, it seems that the information will vanish if I just simply open the new tab with the same url.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome you can try to use `ActionChains` to open duplicate tab by key shortcut

> alt + d, enter

```
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.key_down(Keys.ALT).send_keys('d').perform()
action_chains.key_down(Keys.ENTER).perform()
action_chains.key_up(Keys.ALT).key_up(Keys.ENTER).perform()
```

Comment: A little different... In this way it will not keep the history of the duplicated tab.
Or maybe this question has no answer?

Comment: Sorry, Guy, I have another question... When I ran your code I couldn't open a new tab with the same URL and I don't know why. Can you really do it? Maybe I can't do it because of my environment. May I get the information of your OS, chrome version, driver version, and selenium version?

Comment: @JasonLin I didn't tested that, I don't have Python on my computer.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using chrome as the web driver, you can try to **use selenium to add the extension** "Duplicate tab shortcut" first:

```
chromedriver = "chromedriver.exe"
chrome_options = Options()
chrome_options.add_extension('Path\to\the\crx\file')
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chrome_options)
```

And use `ActionChains` to duplicate the tab:

```
action_chains = ActionChains(driver)
action_chains.key_down(Keys.ALT).key_down(Keys.SHIFT).send_keys('d').perform()
action_chains.key_up(Keys.ALT).key_up(Keys.SHIFT).perform()
```

In this way you can duplicate the tab and keep its history.